# Libgdx Box not drawn with color, but with texture

Tags: java, libgdx

I create simple box using the ModelBuilder from Libgdx new 3d Api.
I create the box like this:

```
int block_size = 5;
Model cube = mBuilder.createBox(block_size, block_size, block_size,
        new Material(), Usage.Position | Usage.Color | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates);
```

Then I create a ModelInstance for rendering like this:

```
ModelInstance instance = new ModelInstance(cube);
```

And then i try to set a Material:

```
instance.materials.first().set(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(t)); //t is a Texture (works)
```

and everything works fine! But if I use ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED) nothing is shown! The box is not visible. I have no clue why...

```
instance.materials.first().set(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED));
```

I tried deleting Usage.TextureCoordinates, but it changed anything. Thank you in advance.
MfG, 
   xyron

Comment: Solved it on my own... Strange solution, but it works! Just delete the Usage.Color ?!?! and the colored block is shown... i don't know if that's the right way... I personally think it's a bug :)

Comment: post it as an answer of your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete Usage.Color

```
Model cube = mBuilder.createBox(block_size, block_size, block_size,
    new Material(), Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates);
```